# How to create a linux shared library including all binary dependencies into a single so file?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker

I'm able to create a shared library in linux libMySharedLibrary.so.

But I'm including a bunch of header files referencing other libraries when I compile. I want to link all the binary code from these included header files so I can distribute my shared library in one .so file.

I'm using gcc to compile. Below the command line:

`gcc -I$JAVA_8_HOME/include/ -I$JAVA_8_HOME/include/linux/ -I./include/ -I. -fPIC -o libMyLibrary.so -shared com__MyLibrary.c`

The header files are inside `./include`. I need to link the generated libMyLibrary.so with the binaries of the header files inside `./include`.

How?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain ***why*** you want to do that. Smells badly as some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). So you should give your motivation and context.

Comment: If you refuse to let your shared library be dependent on any others why
do you expect anybody else to be willing to link against *your* shared library?

Comment: I think you can do it with ldd and patchelf magic.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to link all the binary code from these included header files so I can distribute my shared library in one .so file.

**You cannot do what you want** (and that is against the whole idea of *shared* libraries, which, as their name imply, are *shared* between several [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) and "loaded" into their [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) by the [dynamic linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker)).

You should read Drepper's [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf) paper and the [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/). See also [ld-linux(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld-linux.8.html) & [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) & [objdump(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) & [readelf(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html) & [ld(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html) & [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html). Read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html).

To ease distribution of your software, you may want to build some package (e.g. a [`.deb`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) one) targetting some [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager). And you might publish your source code as [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)).

You could (and perhaps should) link other lower-level shared libraries with your own one. But your user would still need to have these libraries installed. For example, you might compile with

```
 gcc -Wall -O -g -I$JAVA_8_HOME/include/ -I$JAVA_8_HOME/include/linux/ \
     -I./include/ -I. -fPIC -o libMyLibrary.so \
     -shared com__MyLibrary.c -lother
```

and check with `ldd libMyLibrary.so` that it depends on some `libother.so.*` (which your user should have installed to use your `libMyLibrary.so`).

You could compile all the code you are using (as [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code)) -including the source code of "other libraries"- into a *single* shared library, but that is not recommended (if you did that, a program could practicaly not use some shared low-level function in *several* shared libraries above it).

You also need to understand that a library is *not* a set of header files, that is to understand the roles of the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) and of the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprocessor). Header files just describe (partly) the [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) of some C or C++ library. Read also Levine's [*Linkers and Loaders*](http://iecc.com/linkers/) book. In practice, header files *declare* some stuff (classes, functions, variables, types...) and might *define* [inline functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) (but not global ones). You need to understand what [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) are.

You could, with the help of the `/proc/` file system (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)), understand the virtual address space of some given process. For instance, try `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a terminal.

You may read some Linux programming book, perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) (freely downloadable) or something newer. You may read some textbook on operating systems, such as [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (also freely downloadable).

Look also for inspiration into the [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) and build procedure of *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) libraries (e.g. from your Linux distribution, or on [github](http://github.com/) or elsewhere). You should consider using some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)) to build your own library.