# Linking static libraries instead of shared using g++

Tags: linux, g++, static-libraries

I create static library and linking `main.cpp`.
I compile programm using static library, but programm have some dependencies of shared libraries

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf75c1000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf756a000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf754c000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7394000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xf7379000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0xf730b000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0xf70a4000)
libev.so.4 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libev.so.4 (0xf7094000)
libuv.so.1 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 (0xf706c000)           
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf704f000)
```

**Edit**

I try compile my programm, which used only static libraries. A `libHermite.a` is my compiled static library.

```
g++ -o HermitesPolynomialCleanLx-x64 main.cpp -static -L/home/mnowak/projects/HermitesPolynomialLxClean/lib -lHermite -lwebsockets -lstdc++ -lpthread -lssl -lcrypto -ldl -luv -lev -lgcc -lc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread
```

My output:

```
/home/mnowak/projects/HermitesPolynomialLxClean/lib/libcrypto.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x11): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

/home/mnowak/projects/HermitesPolynomialLxClean/lib/libwebsockets.a(lws-plat-unix.c.o): In function `lws_plat_drop_app_privileges':
(.text+0x79e): warning: Using 'initgroups' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

/home/mnowak/projects/HermitesPolynomialLxClean/lib/libwebsockets.a(lws-plat-unix.c.o): In function `lws_plat_drop_app_privileges':
    (.text+0x787): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

/home/mnowak/projects/HermitesPolynomialLxClean/lib/libuv.a(libuv_la-core.o): In function `uv__getpwuid_r':
(.text+0x16e0): warning: Using 'getpwuid_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

/home/mnowak/projects/HermitesPolynomialLxClean/lib/libwebsockets.a(libwebsockets.c.o): In function `lws_get_addresses':
(.text+0x1a9): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking

/home/mnowak/projects/HermitesPolynomialLxClean/lib/libcrypto.a(b_sock.o): In function `BIO_gethostbyname':
(.text+0x71): warning: Using 'gethostbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Comment: Your question lacks some motivation and context. I'm guessing you don't understand well enough why shared libraries are so common, so useful, and much preferable.

Comment: What kind of program do you code?

Comment: But I run this programm on another computer, where maybe shared libraries  have older version.

Comment: A practical (and recommended) possibility would be to transmit your source code on that other computer, and compile there. And many shared libraries are ABI compatible, so might even work (with a minor version mismatch). But you should **edit your question** to motivate it, explain what kind of program you are coding, and why you really need it to be statically linked (I'm guessing your program don't need that).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Linking shared libraries to files make that my programm no have outer dependencies?

Comment: No, your program do have dependencies, like most other programs do. So what? To deal with dependencies, you'll better use a [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager), and that is why your question is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Please explain what kind of program you are coding. Without such an information and the motivation for static linking, your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

> How to compile a program so that the dynamic libraries are linked in the static library built by me.

**This is not possible.** Shared libraries have (in practice) [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code), but static libraries (usually) don't. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129871/841108) answer to a very related question.

Read Drepper's paper [*How To Write Shared Libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf).

I recommend making, as most people do, your shared library, possibly linked to other shared libraries. There are many good reasons to prefer shared libraries.

Or (usually not recommended) make a static library and require your users to link other dependent libraries statically (which is not recommended). e.g. [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) also your & their *executable* with `-Bstatic`

> I would like, that my program using only static library without outer dependencies.

This is usually a wrong wish (which *smells badly* like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)). You should **prefer to *systematically* use shared libraries** (for many reasons, e.g. read [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/)) , like most programs of your Linux distribution do. For instance, of the 6249 executables in my `/usr/bin/` only one `go-md2man` is statically linked.

In 2018, there are very few reasons to statically link an executable (Usually, only few low-level system utilities to be usable after a bad system crash need to be statically linked, and they mostly sit under `/sbin/`).

BTW, your software looks like using some cryptography. This is a *very good* reason to dynamically link it: you want your user to profit from any future bug correction in `libcrypto.so` or `libssl.so` as soon as possible (e.g. when his Linux distribution is updating these).

<sup>(so I think that a cryptographic program which is statically linked is a security risk by itself)</sup>

---

To deal with dependencies, use a [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) and release your thing as e.g. some [`.deb` package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)). But you probably could just transmit the source code of your software, it is often simpler (to let your user rebuild it).